# How do I disable ALL error messages via php.ini?

Tags: php, logging, php.ini

Despite the following settings below, I often see the path to the file producing the error. How do I turn off ALL errors no matter what?

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = off
log_errors = off
```

Comment: What command is giving the error, and what error is it showing?

Comment: @Bort - I would like it not to show file paths assuming there is a coding error, etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The display error statement is not what you actually want.
You should change also the error_reporting value if you don't want to have the messages informing you about the error.

You should try this for all errors

```
error_reporting = off
```

or

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

this will keep letting you know about the errors but they will be invisible to other users..

Comment: Thanks but how do I change it within the php.ini file as opposed to a php file?

Comment: Just be sure to continue logging the errors, otherwise you will wish you did when something bad happens.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey can't you edit the php.ini file with an editor??i guessed the server was at your machine.

Comment: @Jack - Yes it is. I thought that `error_reporting(0);` is limited to PHP files not the php.ini file.

Comment: @Jack - I put the line of code i.e. `error_reporting(0);` and it literally killed the web server. Why is that? I had to remove it before I could bring it back up again.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey you are right, this was my fault, i edited the answer, hope it helps now...